# ASP.Net Web Api 2 JQuery, Empty string passed to getelementbyId();

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm working on an asp.net project that enables renting equipment to customers. I would like to record it in the database.
For this I use Web Api 2 controller and JQuery with AJAX. 
When I try to click submit button nothing happens. Upon inspection, in the console log I get the info that empty string was passed to getelementbyid(); and I'm not sure why is that happening. 
I'm using Firefox for testing, it can be important. 
Here are the controllers:

```
(Web API)
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WinterStore.Models;
using WinterStore.Dtos;

namespace WinterStore.Controllers.api
{
    public class NewRentalsController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public NewRentalsController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateNewRentals(NewRentalDto newRental)
    {
        var customer = _context.Customers.Single(
            c => c.CustomerId == newRental.CustomerId);

        var equipment = _context.Equipment.Where(
            m => newRental.EquipmentIds.Contains(m.Id)).ToList();

        foreach (var equ in equipment)
        {
            if (equ.NumberAvailable == 0)
                return BadRequest("Equipment is not available.");

            equ.NumberAvailable--;

            var rental = new Rental
            {
                Customer = customer,
                Equipment = equ,
                DateRented = DateTime.Now
            };

            _context.Rentals.Add(rental);
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }

}
}
```

(MVC)

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WinterStore.Controllers
{
    public class RentalsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Rentals
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult New()
        {
            return View("AddRental");
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("AddRental");
        }
    }
}
```

Models:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WinterStore.Models
{
    public class Rental
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Equipment Equipment { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateRented { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateReturned { get; set; }
    }
}



    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WinterStore.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Name of the customer")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Name must be 3 or more characters long.")]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    }
}

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using WinterStore.Models;

namespace WinterStore.Models
{
    public class Equipment
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Name must be 2 characters or more")]
        [Display(Name = "Name of the equipment")]
        public string EquipmentName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Price for 1 hour")]
        public double PriceFor1HourOfRent { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Number available in stock")]
        public byte NumberInStock { get; set; }

        public byte NumberAvailable { get; set; }       


        [Display(Name = "Date of rent")]
        public DateTime? DateOfRent { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date of return")]
        public DateTime? DateOfReturn { get; set; }


        public EquipmentType EquipmentType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("EquipmentType")]
        public byte EquipmentTypeId { get; set; }







    }
}

DTo:

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WinterStore.Dtos
{
    public class NewRentalDto
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public List<int> EquipmentIds { get; set; }

     }
}
```

View:

```
@model dynamic
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New Rental Form";
}

<div class="container" id="equipmentcontainer">
    <h2>New Rental Form</h2>
    <form id="newRental">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Customer</label>
            <div class="tt-container">
                <input id="customer" name="customer" data-rule-validCustomer="true" required type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Equipment</label>
            <div class="tt-container">
                <input id="equ" name="equ" data-rule-atLeastOneEquipment="true" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <ul id="equipment" class="list-group"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
  </div>

    @section scripts
{
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var vm = {

                    equipmentIds: []
                };

                var customers = new Bloodhound({
                    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('customerName'),
                    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                    remote: {
                        url: '/api/customers?query=%QUERY',
                        wildcard: '%QUERY'
                    }
                });

                $('#customer').typeahead({
                    minLength: 3,
                    highlight: true
                }, {
                    name: 'customers',
                    display: 'customerName',
                    source: customers
                }).on("typeahead:select", function (e, customer) {
                    vm.customerId = customer.Id;
                });

                var equipment = new Bloodhound({
                    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('equipmentName'),
                    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                    remote: {
                        url: '/api/equipment?query=%QUERY',
                        wildcard: '%QUERY'
                    }
                });

                $('#equ').typeahead({
                    minLength: 3,
                    highlight: true
                }, {
                    name: 'equipment',
                    display: 'equipmentName',
                    source: equipment
                }).on("typeahead:select", function (e, equipment) {
                    $("#equipment").append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + equipment.equipmentName + "</li>");

                    $("#equ").typeahead("val", "");

                    vm.equipmentIds.push(equipment.id);
                });


                $.validator.addMethod("validCustomer", function () {
                    return vm.customerId && vm.customerId !== 0;
                }, "Please select a valid customer.");

                $.validator.addMethod("atLeastEquipment", function () {
                    return vm.equipmentIds.length > 0;
                }, "Please select at least one equipment.");

                var validator = $("#newRental").validate({
                    submitHandler: function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/newRentals",
                            method: "post",
                            data: vm
                        })
                        .done(function () {
                            toastr.success("Rentals successfully recorded.");

                            $("#customer").typeahead("val", "");
                            $("#equ").typeahead("val", "");
                            $("#equipment").empty();

                            vm = { equipmentIds: [] };

                            validator.resetForm();
                        })
                        .fail(function () {
                            toastr.error("Something unexpected happened.");
                        });

                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
    }
```

I suspect, It may have to do with something customer related. The method to validate customer does not work properly as well. (Even when the customer is selected, the validation message is shown).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey I think your not instantiating your class objects in customer or in the controller. Where is the creation of these objects that make up Customer and  everything that in it?

Comment: In my controller I've got " var customer = _context.Customers.Single(
                c => c.CustomerId == newRental.CustomerId);"   and then in the same controller for each equipment "var rental = new Rental
                {
                    Customer = customer,
                    Equipment = equ,
                    DateRented = DateTime.Now
                };"   Should I have it somewhere in the scripts?

Comment: Where is the value of the CurrentId of the customer being Generated?

Comment: Right know im seeing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
$('#customer').typeahead({
                minLength: 3,
                highlight: true
            }, {
                name: 'customers',
                display: 'customerName',
                source: customers
            }).on("typeahead:select", function (e, customer) {
                vm.customerId = customer.Id;
            });
```

I should have used "vm.customerId = customer.customerId; " :P
Working now. 
Thanks Mohamoud Mohamed. :)